# Chrome increase maximum cache size

Tags: google-chrome, caching, size

so my question is simple, how do I increase maximum Chrome caches size? I know that the maximum is 2147483647, because it's an int. How can I change it so the cache size will be stored on a long? I want to have more than 2gb cache. If it is not possible on Chrome, is it on any other browsers?